# Mac Mini Upgrade from 10.5 Leopard to latest Version 10.6.x

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade

I just bought a used Mac Mini that has Leopard OS 10.5.8 Installed on it. How can I upgrade it to the latest version of Leopard (10.6. ?). I mean do I need to go to Apple store to buy a DVD or can I just buy it online ?

I intend to develop iPhone applications.

Comment: If it is an old Mini ie with a Power CPU the 10.5.8 will be the latest - 10.6 requires an Intel chip and 10.7 might not work on all Intel chips

Answer (score 2):

You will need to buy a Snow Leopard DVD from Apple - there is no way to buy a digital only upgrade for Snow Leopard. They're fairly cheap (£26 in Sterling; similar amounts in other currencies). Apple Stores, many computer stores and, of course, the online Apple Store stock them. Other than convenience, there's not much to choose from between the methods.

Comment: Barry and Scott, thanks for the prompt input. I guess I would rather stick with Scott's advise and get the 1O.6 upgrade. No need to get LION for the time being. Iphone development.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy it from many places, including Apple's online store, Amazon, etc. You might want to hold off until next week though. Apple will be announcing their the next version called Lion on Monday. It's due out this summer.

Comment: I'd normally agree about waiting for the next version when it's this close to release, but with Snow Leopard so cheap (Lion will likely be significantly more expensive - well over £100 if it follows previous versions) and with Lion so easy to upgrade to (through the [Snow Leopard only] Mac App Store), I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Barryl and Scott, Thanks so much for your input. I guess I would like to go with Scott's advise and upgrade on the 10.6.x Leopard.